# Reading each column of csv file one after another one

Tags: r

I have a big csv file 360 MB (10240 rows * 7500 columns) and all of values in the file are integer.I want to read each column after another one and operate for example fft on it. but at the first step I dont know exactly how can I read each column after another one in efficient way. I can read for example the first column with colbycol:

```
temptb=cbc.read.table("c:\\users\\Babak\\Desktop\\xxx.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")
tempcol=cbc.get.col(temptb,1)
```

Is there a better way to do this job? How you finde `colClasses`? how can I use it to do this?

Comment: Think about the structure of a CSV file.  Harder to randomly access columns than rows.  What's wrong with just using `fread` to pull the whole thing in quickly?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my problem is now, I dont know, how can I read the columns, I use this command `read.table("MyFile",header=FALSE,sep=",",nrows=3,colClasses=c('numeric'))` but that doesnt work